# XPath select element but exclude children in the result

Tags: xml, xpath, rss

Is it possible to create an XPath that selects an element but removes some children? I have an RSS feed that looks like:

```
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>My Feed</title>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I want an XPath expression that will return the following XML:

```
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>My Feed</title>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Which is just the above XML, but without the `<item>` tags. Is this possible to do with XPath, and if so what does the XPath expression look like?

Comment: Xpath is used for select node from xml file, you can not modify it. you should use xml parser.

Comment: It is not possible to do with xpath. You need xsl. Xpath is to select. When you select `rss` you will end up getting all the children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath expression selects nodes in the source tree (think of it as returning references to those nodes). Those nodes are still in the original tree, and you can navigate from the selected nodes to their ancestors, descendants, and siblings.

It's very common for applications that use XPath to select nodes to then display the entire tree rooted at that node. It's less common (but equally feasible) for the application to navigate to ancestors or siblings of those nodes.

So the first thing is: there aren't any children in the result. You see the children because the application that issues the XPath expression is choosing to navigate from the returned nodes to their children.

If you want to retain some children and drop others, then you are doing transformation rather than just selection, and XPath is therefore no longer the tool for the job: you need XSLT or XQuery.